# Needing to show a time selector in form... jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ive been thinking about this for days... seems simple but I can't wrap my head around it!
We want to make a simple booking form, where people chose a day and then see two columns of available time slots. I already generate a lost of these.
Now I need to display this in buttons, so they can be pressed and only 1 is selected. So if they choose 2pm Wednesday, and then another, the first goes back to the standard color...
This value needs to be loaded in a hidden field to pass on to the next page.

Having searched it seems like the colors are best done in jquery and the hidden field can be populated easily with vanilla js, that part I have working... Help, how add the color change?

ps this is on a bootstrap 3.4 template, not that that should matter but maybe

```
<input type="button" id = "booktime" onclick="change(this)" class="btn btn-default" value=" & thishour & ">

function change(bookingtime) {
  document.getElementById("myInput").value= bookingtime.value;
}
var links = $('#booktime');
links.click(function() {
  links.css('background-color', 'white');
  $(this).css('background-color', 'purple');
});
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the html to make this a runnable [mcve]? I have a sneaky suspicion you are repeating element ID's

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should consider using Radio Buttons versus Buttons. Please see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp *Radio buttons are normally presented in radio groups (a collection of radio buttons describing a set of related options). Only one radio button in a group can be selected at the same time.*

Comment: "They can be pressed and only 1 is selected" What you are describing is `<input type="radio" />`. CSS `:selected` can be used to style it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following HTML and jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".booking label").click(function() {
    var $self = $(this).parent();
    $("input", $self).trigger("click");
    $(".checked").removeClass("checked");
    $self.addClass("checked");
  });
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.booking ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.booking li {
  border: 1px outset rgb(224, 224, 224);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.booking li.checked {
  background: #aaf;
}

.booking li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.booking li input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="booking">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="time-0000" name="time" value="12:00">
        <label for="time-0000">12:00 AM</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="time-0100" name="time" value="01:00">
        <label for="time-0100">1:00 AM</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="time-0200" name="time" value="02:00">
        <label for="time-0200">2:00 AM</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="time-0300" name="time" value="03:00">
        <label for="time-0300">3:00 AM</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" id="time-0400" name="time" value="04:00">
        <label for="time-0400">4:00 AM</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Most of the User Interface is all CSS. You can make it a bit mo9re custom and include a better look and feel with additional JavaScript. The default function of the Radio Button will help.

> Radio buttons are normally presented in radio groups (a collection of radio buttons describing a set of related options). Only one radio button in a group can be selected at the same time.

This will help each button retain a State, either Checked or Unchecked. only one can be `checked` at a time, so we can simple clear the Styling from any other and apply it to the one clicked upon.